# Passing a Wpf control instance to MainWindow Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection, .net-4.5

Assume a 'standard' Wpf project with a MainWindow.xaml/cs. By default, elements referenced in the xaml (such as a  with a child , and a ) are created in the autogenerated code.

What do I have to do so I can reference my instances in the XAML, but pass the actual instances to the MainWindow constructor?

I already have modified the App.xaml/cs to allow me to call the MainWindow custom ctor. But I am unsure how to set my custom instances into MainWindow so initialization still works.

Comment: I think you should explain it better - maybe with some (pseudo) code to illustrate. What means "such as a width a child, and a"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem as follows (probably obvious to experienced Wpf Users):

I simple create the parent objects (TabItem etc), and set their .Content member to my passed-in reference.